# Parallel package, border

Tags: parallel

I have such preamble and the code.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,14pt ]{report}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{parallel,enumitem}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{par}{\par}
\captionsetup{labelsep=par,justification=centering}
\graphicspath{{images/}}


\newcommand\tablecaption[1]{
\captionsetup{labelsep=par,justification=centering}
\caption{#1}
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm}
\geometry{right=1cm}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}

     \begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}{0.40\textwidth}{0.65\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{\noindent
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1ex]
      \item{Vertices are sorted in the following order 0,5,1,2,4,3}
      \item{Depth 1: \textbf{0},5,1,2,4,3} \\
      Depth 2: \textbf{1},2 \\
      Depth 3: \textbf{2} \\
      Depth 2: 1,\textbf{2}
      \item{Depth 1: 0,\textbf{5},1,2,4,3} \\
      Depth 2: \textbf{4},3 \\
      \item{Depth 1: 0,5,\textbf{1},2,4,3} \\
      Depth 2: \textbf{2},3,4 \\
      Depth 3: \textbf{3},4 \\
      Depth 4: \textbf{4} \\
      Depth 3: 3,\textbf{4} \\
      Depth 2: 2,3,\textbf{4} \\
      \item{Depth 1: 0,5,1,\textbf{2},4,3}
    \end{enumerate}
    }
\ParallelRText{\noindent
    \\\\ (the bold face node is expanded)
    \\\\
    Cannot expand, so $CBC$ is \{0,1,2\} with size 3 \\
    $d + (m - i)= 2 + (2 - 2) = 2 < 3,$ so we prune \\\\
    $2 + (2-1)=3 \le CBC$, so we prune
   \\\\ \\\\
    becomes our new $CBC$ with size 4 \\
    $3 + (2 - 2) = 3 < 4$, so we prune \\
    $2 + (3 - 2) = 3 < CBC$, so we prune \\\\
    $1 + (6 - 4) = 3 < CBC$, as depth = 1, we stop
}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}
    \end{document}
```

I have compiled it and have a good result, but when I have added it to the document with such preambula the border has changed. 
[image]

How can I do it as it shown at the picture:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but how can your MWE compile? There are two preambles inside.

Comment: I'm sorry, i have 2 preambles. I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: @user565447 Leave off the `hyperref` package and everything looks as in your second image.

Comment: @user565447 Please don't delete the code of your question. Leaving the question as it is now won't help other users with the same or with a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, this depends on your actual usage/document layout, but I would rather go with a [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) layout than use the [`parallel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parallel). For one, the code is structured on a line-by-line basis, rather than left-and-right chunks separated in blocks, improving readability in your code.

Here's your example, "minimimalised" for the sake of brevity:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize

\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\geometry{left=3cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rl@{\quad}X}
  1 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Vertices are sorted in the following order 0,5,1,2,4,3} \\[\baselineskip]
  2 & Depth 1: \textbf{0},5,1,2,4,3 & (the bold face node is expanded) \\
    & Depth 2: \textbf{1},2 \\
    & Depth 3: \textbf{2} & Cannot expand, so $CBC$ is \{0,1,2\} with size 3 \\
    & Depth 2: 1,\textbf{2} & $d + (m - i)= 2 + (2 - 2) = 2 < 3,$ so we prune \\[\baselineskip]
  3 & Depth 1: 0,\textbf{5},1,2,4,3 \\
    & Depth 2: \textbf{4},3 & $2 + (2-1)=3 \le CBC$, so we prune \\[\baselineskip]
  4 & Depth 1: 0,5,\textbf{1},2,4,3 \\
    & Depth 2: \textbf{2},3,4 \\
    & Depth 3: \textbf{3},4 \\
    & Depth 4: \textbf{4} & becomes our new $CBC$ with size 4 \\
    & Depth 3: 3,\textbf{4} & $3 + (2 - 2) = 3 < 4$, so we prune \\
    & Depth 2: 2,3,\textbf{4} & $2 + (3 - 2) = 3 < CBC$, so we prune \\[\baselineskip]
  5 & Depth 1: 0,5,1,\textbf{2},4,3 & $1 + (6 - 4) = 3 < CBC$, as depth = 1, we stop
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The gap between the "Depth" and "description" is `\quad`.

The only drawback is that this implementation will not break across the page boundary. However, I'm not sure whether this is at all necessary.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to leave `hyperref` as suggested by @Thorsten. But if you want to keep `hyperref` this will be helpful.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt ]{report}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{par}{\par}
\captionsetup{labelsep=par,justification=centering}
\graphicspath{{images/}}


\newcommand\tablecaption[1]{
\captionsetup{labelsep=par,justification=centering}
\caption{#1}
}

\onehalfspacing
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\normalsize
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3cm}
\geometry{right=1cm}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[parsep=-10pt,itemsep=3ex,leftmargin=0.5cm]
      \item{Vertices are sorted in the following order 0,5,1,2,4,3}
    \end{enumerate}

\begin{Parallel}{0.35\textwidth}{0.63\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{\noindent
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=3ex,leftmargin=0.5cm,rightmargin=.65\textwidth]
      \item{Depth 1: \textbf{0},5,1,2,4,3} \\
      Depth 2: \textbf{1},2 \\
      Depth 3: \textbf{2} \\
      Depth 2: 1,\textbf{2}
        \end{enumerate}
      }
\ParallelRText{\noindent
\\\\(the bold face node is expanded)
    \\\\
    Cannot expand, so $CBC$ is \{0,1,2\} with size 3 \\
    $d + (m - i)= 2 + (2 - 2) = 2 < 3,$ so we prune

}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[resume*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=3ex,leftmargin=0.5cm,rightmargin=.65\textwidth]
      \item{Depth 1: 0,\textbf{5},1,2,4,3} \\
      Depth 2: \textbf{4},3 
          \end{enumerate}
      }
\ParallelRText{\noindent
 \\\\ \\$2 + (2-1)=3 \le CBC$, so we prune
}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[resume*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=3ex,leftmargin=0.5cm,rightmargin=.65\textwidth]
      \item{Depth 1: 0,5,\textbf{1},2,4,3} \\
      Depth 2: \textbf{2},3,4 \\
      Depth 3: \textbf{3},4 \\
      Depth 4: \textbf{4} \\
      Depth 3: 3,\textbf{4} \\
      Depth 2: 2,3,\textbf{4}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\ParallelRText{\noindent
  \\\\\\\\\\ becomes our new $CBC$ with size 4 \\
    $3 + (2 - 2) = 3 < 4$, so we prune \\
    $2 + (3 - 2) = 3 < CBC$, so we prune 

}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\noindent 
\begin{enumerate}[resume*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=3ex,leftmargin=0.5cm,rightmargin=.65\textwidth]
      \item{Depth 1: 0,5,1,\textbf{2},4,3}
    \end{enumerate}
    }
\ParallelRText{\noindent
 \\\\ $1 + (6 - 4) = 3 < CBC$, as depth = 1, we stop
}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: than you for answer it has helped