# "Nice" way to list pro and contra aspects

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I am currently evaluating different alternatives and would like to present a few pro and contra arguments for each possibility. My first thought was to present these arguments side-by-side using two minipages of equal width, each containing a `itemize` environment.

But that seems a little hackish to me. Maybe there are packages or even standard environments that are suited to enumerate pro and contra arguments? If not, how would you do this in general?

If it matters: This is for a document using `\documentclass{scrreprt}`. Oh and sorry, for the tags, I couldn't think of better ones (maybe that's why Google couldn't quite help me with this ...).

Comment: May be you can use `parallel` package and this answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53581/parallel-package-border/53591#53591) is useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following puts them in two columns in a sort-of table.

- The `tabularx` package is used with the `X` column specification to make the table width exactly the line width.
- The `booktabs` package and its command `\toprule`, `\cmidrule` and `\bottomrule` are for pretty horizontal lines (notice that optional arguments of `\cmidrule` in `()` are used to make the line broken in a nice way)
- The `lipsum` package and `\lipsum` command only provides some dummy text and are not needed.
- I make the points with no bullets and seperated by some vertical space (specified by `>` directive in the `tabularx` argument).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\parskip1ex}X@{\kern4\tabcolsep}>{\parskip1ex}X}
\toprule
\hfil\bfseries Pros
&
\hfil\bfseries Cons
\\\cmidrule(r{3\tabcolsep}){1-1}\cmidrule(l{-\tabcolsep}){2-2}

%% PROS, seperated by empty line or \par
It's nice\par
\lipsum[1]
It's very nice\par

&

%% CONS, seperated by empty line or \par
It's ugly\par
It's really ugly\par
\lipsum[4]

\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Pros and cons of ...}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That does look very nice, I actually really like that you didn't use bullet points.

Comment: @yo Is  there a way to add a footnote there? I wrote "It's nice\footnote{something}\par", but only the little number appers: the word "something" doesn't appear anywhere